# Read An Excel File With OLEDB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, oledb

Hi I am reading an excel file with oledb(The file has 100000  rows). I must read file quickly.

```
string conn;

                conn = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                ("Data Source=" + _filename + ";" +
                "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;\""));
                OleDbConnection oleDBCon = new OleDbConnection(conn);
                oleDBCon.Open();
                DataTable dt = oleDBCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string excelsheetname = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                string SSQL = "SELECT * from [" + excelsheetname + "]";

                OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(SSQL, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                oleDA.Fill(ds);
                DataTable _DtTable = ds.Tables[0]; // or [ ds ]
                oleDBCon.Close();
```

and then in _DtTable with a for loop I am inserting these cells to DB..  How can I read this very large excel quickly? And insert to DB? I used Parallel.For but it is not true solution for me.. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add records to MyTable using ADO, you can use code similar to the following:

```
'Create a new connection object for Book1.xls
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
  "Data Source=C:\Book1.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
conn.Execute "Insert into MyTable (FirstName, LastName)" & _
  " values ('Bill', 'Brown')"
conn.Execute "Insert into MyTable (FirstName, LastName)" & _
  " values ('Joe', 'Thomas')"
conn.Close
```

This is from MSDN: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247412

Comment: I probably didn't read carefully enough. You wish to read from excel and insert into another DB, maybe SQL Server and not insert records in Excel file.

To read excel files i prefer to use ExcelDataReader from http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Comment: thank you! but on first line it says "Lightweight and fast library written in C# for reading Microsoft Excel files ('97-2007)." I have excel 03/07/10 files.. Does ExcelDataReader support excel 2010 files?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of OpenXML of SQL to insert data in bulk which do fater work for you

here is code did by me for same work : [Bulk Insertion of Data Using C# DataTable and SQL server OpenXML function](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/12/bulk-insertion-of-data-using-c.html)

Comment: this is useful solution for insert? I didnt tired it? Are you sure is your code more good performance than from classic for loop on Datatable(like ı write up) ??

Answer (score 1):

You could look at some of the ways the database can consume [Excelfiles](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1207/different-options-for-importing-data-into-sql-server/)